# Using Google Slides Api is it possible to determine the Object Animation of a Page Element i.e. 'show element on click'?

Tags: vb.net, google-slides-api

I would like to know programmatically how many 'click' events are on each slide.

Comment: You can't; Slides API doesn't have methods for viewing/editing/creating animation profiles.

Comment: Ok many thanks, much appreciated. T